# Setwise convergence to the Lebesgue measure on the unit square

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, weak-convergence

Let our sample space be the unit square, $E = [0,1]^2$. Consider the measurable space $(E,\mathcal{B})$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel sigma algebra on $E$.

Let $\mu_n$ be the finitely supported probability measure, defined by $\mu_n(\{x\})=\frac{1}{n^2}$ for all $x \in E$ of the form $x=(i/n,j/n)$, $i,j \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$, and $0$ otherwise.

I have to show that the sequence of measures $\mu_n$ converges *setwise* to the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]^2$. Let us call it $\mu$.

My attempt: I have been able to show that $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ weakly, by showing that the CDF's converge pointwise, using the definition of the Reimann integral as the limit of Reimann sums. But I'm getting confused showing that the area of *any* set converges.

Comment: I don't think it converges set wise s you claim you need to prove. Take the set $A$ of points in $[0.1]^2$ that have irrational components. The $\mu_n(A)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ while $\mu(A)=1$. The sequence does, however, converge weakly to $\mu$ as you observed.